# How to search from the start of a file in recent versions of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ide

This sounds ridiculous on the surface, but [this unresolved/closed issue with Microsoft](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/14704/find-again-does-not-search-from-the-cursor-positio.html) makes it clear it is happening for others too.

Search for something and find it in the lower half of a file. Now go to the top of the file, and try to search for a character you can see on the screen. I hope you succeed. You probably will. But for me (and others clearly), Visual Studio leaps down to where the previous search ended, and finds the character there.

Whoa. No. Stop. This is a new search. I went to the top of the file deliberately to search for something new and unrelated. Maybe it doesn't happen for you, but it is happening for me in VS Community 2015. It never used to happen, but this week it is, and it's utterly infuriating. How do I turn it off? What is it called?

I doubt that it matters, but I'm running Windows 7. The user with the issue reported above was running Win 10 and VS 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Oops: embarrassing - somehow the find direction in the CTRL+F search box got set to searching backwards. F3 still searches for the next match forwards, and SHIFT+F3 searches backwards, but the starting direction was set to search backwards courtesy of the drop-down option I swear I never knew existed, let alone clicked on. I cannot find any key combination that changes this search direction default, but either one exists, or I managed to click the combo-box and choose and option on the list without noticing it.